# how to stop "\newpage" in \chapter

Tags: spacing, chapters

I'm using a `memoir` style.

This one to be exact.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\STARTCODE\relax 
\let\STOPCODE\relax 
\STARTCODE
\usepackage{fourier} % or what ever
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}%. Sans serif - Helvetica
\usepackage{color,calc}
\newsavebox{\ChpNumBox}
\definecolor{ChapBlue}{rgb}{0.00,0.65,0.65}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\thickhrulefill}{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1\p@ \hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand*\BuildChpNum[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \makebox[0pt][c]{#1\strut}  \\[.5ex]
    \colorbox{ChapBlue}{%
      \rule[-10em]{0pt}{0pt}%
      \rule{1ex}{0pt}\color{black}#2\strut
      \rule{1ex}{0pt}}%
  \end{tabular}}
\makechapterstyle{BlueBox}{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\large\scshape}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\raggedright\Huge\bfseries}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{20pt}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{26pt}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{40pt}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
    \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
      \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\@chapapp}%
      {\chapnumfont\thechapter}}}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{%
    \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
      \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\vphantom{\@chapapp}}%
      {\chapnumfont\hphantom{\thechapter}}}}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
    \parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
      \vspace{\midchapskip}%
      \thickhrulefill\par
      \chaptitlefont ##1\par}}%
}
\chapterstyle{BlueBox}
\STOPCODE
\setlength\afterchapskip {\onelineskip }
\setlength\beforechapskip {\onelineskip }

%ligando a numeração da subsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}

%alterando nome da tabela e da figura
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura: }
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela: }

%Margem
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3cm}

%tamanho que o texto ocupa
\textwidth=16cm

%fazendo os footers
\pagestyle{plain}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%para tabelas grandes
\usepackage{longtable}

%para colocar um width maximo para as figuras do comando
%[max width = ...]
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%packages inseridos que não são do estilo.

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

And everytime I use the command `\chapter{title}` sometimes it skips a page.
I guess to start every chapter in a odd or even page.
Is there a way to stop this `\newpage`?

It is ok if the new chapter starts in a new page. but I'd like to not have any blank pages.

Comment: memoir has `[openany]` option the same as the standard classes to allow opening pages on either side

Comment: Or you can use `[oneside]` so that it uses the same page style on all pages with no odd/even distinction

Comment: You never gave feedback to @DavidCarlisle's suggestions. Is your question answered or are you still interested in a solution?

Comment: still interested in a solution...

Comment: @Guilherme the code in the question is not useful to demonstrate the problem, delete any packages not needed to show this problem, and make the example into a complete document to `\end{document}` which has a blank page before `\chapter` which does not go if you use `\documentclass[openany]{memoir}` then someone can debug the problem.

Comment: Do @DavidCarlisle's suggestion help you? And if not, why?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't use the [openary] my problem is if the chapter would start in a even page, it gives a \newpage to the chapter start in a odd page, I just want to stop it.

Comment: That is exactly what `[openany]` is designed to stop it says to let chapter open on odd or even page and not throw a blank page. If it is not working, you need to give an example to show it not working

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You were right. Thanks... Thats why I was writing openaRy, not openaNy [guess I need glasses]

Comment: Thanks for your hel @DavidCarlisle. =] and patience too.

Comment: OK if that is the issue I'll make it an answer and this loop can be closed:-)

Answer (score 2):

`memoir` (like most classes) has an  `[openany]` option the same as the standard classes to allow opening pages on either side.

After

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
```

`\chapter` is not constrained to open on an odd page, and so will not throw a blank page but simply place the heading on an even or odd page depending on the current position.